# PIC16F877 analog pin configuration

Tags: microcontroller, pic, embedded, microchip

I've been working with **PIC16F877**. Can someone please explain how to configure its pins to be analog or digital?

I saw somewhere that we need to configure `ADCON1`, but don't really understand how that works.

Comment: This sounds like a better question for http://s.tk/ee

Comment: Check datasheet: http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/30292c.pdf page 112

Comment: What language/compiler are you using?

Answer (score 2):

See [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/30292c.pdf), Section 11.0 (Register 11-2), page 112.

You select the operation of the pins by setting the four bits `PCFG3:PCFG0` in the `ADCON1` register
according to the table in the datasheet.

The power-on default of these bits is `0000`, which means that all the pins **AN0...AN7** are configured as analog inputs.

To configure all the **AN**-pins as digital, you set the `PCFG` bits to `011x` (*x* means *don't care*). The rest of the combinations are in the datasheet.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just using the pins for output, they don't have to be configured as digital. That is only required for digital inputs. It's implied by all the data sheets, but a lot of people don't realise it. It is mentioned in the data sheets for the latest parts.

Comment: I'm not so sure this is really true for all parts, especially older ones like the 16F877.  I seem to remember running into this problem long ago wondering why my pin wasn't wiggling and not realizing that analog functions had to be disabled.  I have seen what you are talking about in newer datasheets, but that doesn't mean it applies to older parts.

Comment: From the A/D conversion chapter of the datasheet: If the TRIS bit is cleared (output), the digital output level (V_OH or V_OL) will be converted.